# Not able to show the saved items in a ListView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to display the items of my `_saved` list (which is in the `FavoritesList` page) in a ListView on the `FavoritesList` page(which is triggered when the `FAB` is clicked, and **here we check the items to save**) of my app. I want my app to show only the checked items in the ListView, when I click the local back button, on the `SecondPage` of the app(which is the second tab in my app).

My `SecondPage` tab code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'favoritelist.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return 
   Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!❤',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150, color: Colors.blue[100]),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 250),
    FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
);
 }
 }
```

My `FavoritesList` page code:

```
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
 }

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
// bool isChecked = false;

  final Set _saved = Set();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Add to Favorites!'), centerTitle:  true, backgroundColor: 
     Colors.red),
      // backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
     body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          // value: _saved.contains(context), // changed 
          value: _saved.contains(index),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              // isChecked = val;           // changed 
              // if(val == true){           // changed 
              //   _saved.add(context);     // changed 
              // } else{                    // changed 
              //   _saved.remove(context);  // changed 
              // }                          // changed 
              if(val == true){
                _saved.add(index);
              } else{
                _saved.remove(index);
              }
            });
          },
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text(nameOfSite[index]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: user any state management techniques for this kind of jobs. Or you can pass data from favorites page to previous page on it's pop method

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to select a list of items in the second page of your app and then display only selected items in you first page right?

In that case, you'll have to store the list of selected items outside of both of the pages, i.e. in the parent widget of the `PageView` widget and use that to update/show selected items.

Comment: @HasilT its not returning the list to the `SecondPage` on checking the items and then clicking back button. What now?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi yeah but on checking and clicking the items its not returning anything so how will it work